# Sending JavaScript variables to fragment shader

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I have been piecing together online examples to make a Mandelbrot Set fragment shader. The vertex shader does basically nothing, it assigns `gl_Position` and the fragment shader does some math to calculate the image.

However, I have a number of `#define`s that I want to replace with JavaScript controlled variables and I do not know how to do this. If an example could be shown on how to say replace `#define MAX_ITERATIONS 200` with a JavaScript assigned variable in the code below I could probably figure out the rest of them. I believe that I need to specify a `uniform` or `varying` but am not sure how to manage the communication from JavaScript to GLSL.

Also I don't understand how `aPosition` works between JavaScript and the vertex shader, what I have is basically the same as the examples.

**JavaScript**, I would imagine only `init()` matters for SO readers, the rest is posted if needed:

```
var canvas, gl, shaderProgram;

function draw() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw, canvas);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");

    gl = initGl(canvas);
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialize WebGL");
        return;
    }

    shaderProgram = initShaders();
    if (!shaderProgram) {
        alert("Could not initialize shaders");
        return;
    }

    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(
        gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        new Float32Array([
            -1.0,  -1.0,
            1.0,  -1.0,
            -1.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 1.0,
        ]),
        gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;

    var aPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    draw();
}

function initGl(inCanvas) {
    gl = false;

    try { gl = inCanvas.getContext("webgl") || inCanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"); }
    catch (e) {}

    return !gl ? false : gl;
}

function initShaders() {
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById("vertexShader").text);

    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        return false;
    }

    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text);

    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        return false;
    }

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) return false;
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    return shaderProgram;
}
```

**Vertex Shader**:

```
attribute vec2 aPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**, `MAX_ITERATIONS`, `XMIN`, `YMIN`, and `WH` should be controlled in JavaScript:

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGEMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    precision highp float;
#else
    precision mediump float;
#endif
precision mediump int;

#define MAX_ITERATIONS 200
#define XMIN -2.5
#define YMIN -2.0
#define WH 4.0

#define LOG_TWO log(2.0)
#define LOG_MAX log(200.0)

void main() {
    // Normalized pixel position to complex plane position
    float maxPwh = max(640.0, 480.0);
    float x = XMIN+(gl_FragCoord.x/maxPwh)*WH;
    float y = YMIN+(gl_FragCoord.y/maxPwh)*WH;

    // Complex plane window offsets for pixel windows that are not square
    float halfDelta = WH/maxPwh*0.5;
    x -= min((640.0-480.0)*halfDelta, 0.0);
    y -= min((480.0-640.0)*halfDelta, 0.0);

    // Mandelbrot Set code
    float zr = x;
    float zi = y;
    int iterations = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        iterations = i;

        float sqZr = zr*zr;
        float sqZi = zi*zi;
        float twoZri = 2.0*zr*zi;
        zr = sqZr-sqZi+x;
        zi = twoZri+y;

        if (sqZr+sqZi > 16.0) break;
    }

    if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS-1) gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else {
        float fn = float(iterations)+1.0-log(log(sqrt(zr*zr+zi*zi)))/LOG_TWO;
        float logVal = log(fn)/LOG_MAX;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(logVal, logVal, logVal, 1.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The short answer is you have basically 2 options

1. Pass values from JavaScript to GLSL by uniform.

   For example if you want to pass a float create a float uniform

   ```
   uniform float foo;
   ```

   In JavaScript compile and link that shader, then lookup the location of the uniform

   ```
   var locationOfFoo = gl.getUniformLocation(someProgram, "foo");
   ```

   You can now pass a value to GLSL with

   ```
   gl.useProgram(someProgram)
   gl.uniform1f(locationOfFoo, valueToPass);
   ```
2. Manipulate strings before compiling the shader

   ```
   #define MAX_INTERATIONS %maxIterations%
   #define XMIN %xMin%
   ```

   ...

   ```
   var maxIterations = 123;
   var xMin = 4.5;
   shaderSource = shaderSource.replace(/%maxIterations%/g, maxIterations);
   shaderSource = shaderSource.replace(/%xMin%/g, xMin);
   ```

(1) above is for passing stuff that changes often. #2 is for changing a shader before it's compiled. #1 is a technique used in pretty much 100% of WebGL programs. #2 is used often when generating shaders on the fly which many game engines do.

Answer (score 5):

It took me about 45 minutes to implement **gman's** answer because
I kept making stupid little mistakes. So here is a **full working code
sample** that creates an adjustable tile-map.

Tested In: **Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Edge:**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML >
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>         GL_TILE_TESTBED           </title>
    <!-- AUTHOR: John Mark Isaac Madison           -->
    <!-- EMAIL : J4M4I5M7@hotmail.com              -->
    <!-- SSSSSSSSS SHADER_SECTION START  SSSSSSSSS -->
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
    <style>
       
        p{ font-size:12pt;}
        h3,p,input,button,br{ 
            padding:0px; 
            margin:0px; 
            font-family:"Andale Mono";
        }
        button,input{
            padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script id="VERT_SHADER" type="NOT_JAVASCRIPT">
      precision highp float;
      
      attribute vec2 a_position;
      void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
      }
    </script>
    
    
    <script id="FRAG_SHADER" type="NOT_JAVASCRIPT">
    
      //Must declare precision before declaring
      //any uniforms:
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////
      #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
        precision highp float;
      #else
        precision mediump float;
      #endif
      precision mediump int;
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
      #define CANVAS_WID  640.0
      #define CANVAS_HIG  480.0
    
      #define TIL_WID     64.0
      #define TIL_HIG     64.0
      
      //Uniforms exposed to HTML/JAVASCRIPT:
      uniform float TIL_WID_EDIT;
      uniform float TIL_HIG_EDIT;
     
      float til_wid;
      float til_hig;
      
    
      void main() {
    
        //If uniforms have not set by user,
        //use the default values set by the #define(s)
        //==========================================//
        if(TIL_WID_EDIT > 0.0){
          til_wid = TIL_WID_EDIT;
        }else{
          til_wid = TIL_WID;
        }
        
        if(TIL_HIG_EDIT > 0.0){
          til_hig = TIL_HIG_EDIT;
        }else{
          til_hig = TIL_HIG;
        }
        //==========================================//
        
        //NOTE: on "gl_FragCoord" range:
        //******************************************//
        //web-gl: In terms of pixel/canvas coords.
        //OpenGL: In terms of 0 to 1.
        //******************************************//
        
        //:Calculate number of tiles shown on screen:
        //:This may be fractional:
        float NUM_TIL_X = CANVAS_WID / til_wid;
        float NUM_TIL_Y = CANVAS_HIG / til_hig;
    
        
        vec2 FC_MOD;
        FC_MOD.x = gl_FragCoord.x;
        FC_MOD.y = gl_FragCoord.y;
        
        //You want all tiles to have the full range 
        //of colors, so you always modulate by 
        //CANVAS_WID and CANVAS_HIG, You scale by the 
        //# of tiles on each axis which means the 
        //gradient becomes steeper as the # of tiles
        //increases.
        FC_MOD.x = mod( gl_FragCoord.x*NUM_TIL_X, CANVAS_WID );
        FC_MOD.y = mod( gl_FragCoord.y*NUM_TIL_Y, CANVAS_HIG );
        
        //[N]ormalize values into range 0 to 1:
        //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN//
        float norm_X = (FC_MOD.x) / CANVAS_WID;
        float norm_Y = (FC_MOD.y) / CANVAS_HIG;
        //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN//
        
        //Use [B]lue channel because why not?
        //BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB//
        float GRAD_X = gl_FragCoord.x / CANVAS_WID;
        //BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB//
     
        //Set the final [F]ragment colors:
        //FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF//
        gl_FragColor = vec4(norm_X, norm_Y, GRAD_X, 1.0);
        //FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF//
      }
    </script>
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSS SHADER_SECTION END  SSSSSSSSSS -->
    </head> 
    <!-- HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH -->
             
    <!-- BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB -->                    
    <body onload="ON_LOADED_FUNCTION()" >
    <!-- BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB -->
    
        <h3> Open GL Tile TestBed            <h3>
        <p> Author: John Mark Isaac Madison <p>
        <p> Email : J4M4I5M7@hotmail.com    <p>
    
        <canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas>
        
        </br>
        <button onClick="PUT_WID();">TILE_WIDTH__IN_PIXELS</button> 
        <input type="text" id="INPUT_WID" value="45">
        </br>
        
        </br>
        <button onClick="PUT_HIG();">TILE_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS</button> 
        <input type="text" id="INPUT_HIG" value="45">
        </br>
        
        
         
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->   
    <script id="BOILER_PLATE_CODE">
        function ON_LOADED_FUNCTION(){
            console.log("[ON_LOADED_FUNCTION]");
            main();
        }
        
        //:Takes the gl context object, if the input
        //:is null, we likely failed to get the
        //:context.
        function HAS_OPEN_GL_CHECK(gl){
          // Only continue if WebGL is 
          // available and working
          if (!gl) {
            var msg = "";
            msg += "[Unable to initialize WebGL.]";
            msg += "[your browser or machine may]";
            msg +=  "[not support it.]"
            alert( msg );
            return;
          }
        }
        
        function GET_INPUT_BOX_VALUE( elem_id ){
            var box; //DOM input box
            var val; //Value in input box.
            box = document.getElementById( elem_id );
            val = box.value;
            return (0 + val); //cast to number.
        }
        
        function PUT_WID(){
            assert_program_and_gl_exist();
            var val = GET_INPUT_BOX_VALUE("INPUT_WID");
            SET_ATTR("TIL_WID_EDIT", val);
        }
        
        function PUT_HIG(){
            assert_program_and_gl_exist();
            var val = GET_INPUT_BOX_VALUE("INPUT_HIG");
            SET_ATTR("TIL_HIG_EDIT", val); 
        }
        
        function SET_ATTR(gl_var_name, val){
            if(val < 0 || val > 256 ){
                alert("choose value between 0 to 256");
                return;
            }
         
            var loc; //<--location of variable.
            loc = gl.getUniformLocation(
                program    , 
                gl_var_name
            );
            gl.useProgram(program);
            gl.uniform1f(loc, val);
        }
        
        function assert_program_and_gl_exist(){
            if(!program){慌("[NO_PROGRAM_EXISTS]");}
            if(!gl     ){慌("[NO_GL_EXISTS]");}
        }
        
        //慌: "disconcerted, be confused, lose one's head"
        //慌: In Code: ~Panic~
        function 慌( panic_message ){
            console.log( panic_message );
            alert      ( panic_message );
            throw      ( panic_message );
        }
      
        function makeOpenGlContextUsingCanvas(c){
            
            //:Try what works in chrome and all the
            //:respectable browsers first:
            gl = c.getContext("webgl");
            
            if(!gl){
                console.log("[Probably_In_IE]");
                gl = c.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            }else{
                console.log("[Probably_NOT_IE]");
            }
            
            HAS_OPEN_GL_CHECK( gl );
            return gl;
        }
        
        //: No "var" prefix, making them global:
        function initGlobals(){
            canvas = document.querySelector("#glCanvas");
            if(!canvas){
                alert("FAILED_TO_GET_CANVAS");
            }else{
                console.log("[GOT_CANVAS]");
            }
            
            gl = makeOpenGlContextUsingCanvas(canvas);
            
            
            //These dimensions are hard-coded into
            //fragment shader code, so be careful
            //about changing them:
            canvas.width = 640;
            canvas.height= 480;
        
            buffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
            gl.bufferData(
            gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            new Float32Array([
              -1.0, -1.0, 
               1.0, -1.0, 
              -1.0,  1.0, 
              -1.0,  1.0, 
               1.0, -1.0, 
               1.0,  1.0]), 
            gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );
            
            //G == Global Container.
            //To fix problems with rendering in I.E.
            //(Internet Explorer)
            //GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG//
            var G = {}; 
            G.canvas = canvas;
            G.gl     = gl;
            G.buffer = buffer;
            
            if( ! G.canvas ||
                ! G.gl     ||
                ! G.buffer  ){
                慌("[Global_Container_Broken]");
            }
            
            return G;
            //GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG//
        }
        
        function main(){
        
          G = initGlobals();
          HAS_OPEN_GL_CHECK( G );
          
          gl.viewport(0,0,gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    
          setup();
          render();
        }
        
        function setup(){
            var frag_dom = document.getElementById("FRAG_SHADER");
            var frag_src = frag_dom.text;
            console.log( frag_src );
    
            F = createShader(
                gl,gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag_src
            );
    
            var vert_dom = document.getElementById("VERT_SHADER");
            var vert_src = vert_dom.text;
            console.log( vert_src );
    
            V = createShader(
                gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vert_src
            );
    
            //**** MAKE "program" a GLOBAL VAR  ****//
            program = createProgram(gl,V,F);
            gl.useProgram( program );
            
            if(!program){
                慌("PROGRAM_IS_NULL");
            }
        }
        
        function render(){
          window.requestAnimationFrame(render,canvas);
        
          // Set clear color to black, fully opaque
          gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
          
          // Clear the color buffer with specified clear color
          gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
          
          //Directly before call to gl.drawArrays:
          positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
          gl.enableVertexAttribArray( positionLocation );
          gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
          
          
          gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        }
        
        function createShader(gl,type,source){
            //:Error Check For Bad Inputs:
            if(!gl    ){慌("[NULL_GL]");}
            if(!type  ){慌("[NULL_TY]");}
            if(!source){慌("[NULL_SR]");}
        
            var shader = gl.createShader(type);
            gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
            gl.compileShader(shader);
            var res = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
            if( res ){
                console.log("[SHADER_COMPILED!]");
                return shader;
            }
            
            console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            gl.deleteShader(shader);
            慌("[FAILED_TO_COMPILE_SHADER]");
        }
        
        //:gl  : openGL context :
        //:vert: vertex shader  :
        //:frag: fragment shader:
        function createProgram(gl,vert, frag){
            var program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vert);
            gl.attachShader(program, frag);
            gl.linkProgram (program);
            var res = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
            if( res ){
                console.log("[PROGRAM_CREATED!]");
                return program;
            }
            
            console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
            gl.deleteProgram(program);
        }
    
    </script>
    <!-- SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS -->
         
    <!-- BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB -->
    </body>
    </html>
```